# Test Lua bytecode integrity

Tags: lua, bytecode

A couple of my friends and I run a game which allows scripting using Lua. This is implemented through LuaJ which is a java program implementing the Lua language. I recently learned native Lua has an issue with bytecode manipulation where you can change pieces of the bytecode and run it back using loadstring to access variables and environments normally out of a functions scope even to the point of accessing functions in C that Lua is written on. This could possibly prove hazardous for our game so I tried to convince my friends we need to disable loadstring however they said since we use LuaJ and not Lua that there is no way the bug exists in our version too. I don't like assuming something cant be broken just because its different from something else that can be. Would anyone here happen to know how to set up some pentests to try and manipulate LuaJ bytecode and see if it is just as vulnerable as native Lua? Below are some links from a similar hack that almost hit a game called ROBLOX. Their system was written on the native Lua not LuaJ.

http://www.corsix.org/content/lua-514-bug-recap

http://www.corsix.org/lua/bytecode_abuse_0_1.lua

my biggest concern with the game as everything should be sandboxed is one bytecode manipulation as demonstrated in the top link

> **Accessing other function's locals**
>   
>   
>    The VM call instruction is traditionally done at the top of the stack. However, through bytecode manipulation, it can be done in the middle of the stack, and then after the call is complete, any locals used by the called function will be left at the top of the stack.

Comment: Have you attempted to set up your own pentests yet? Have you tried manipulating the bytecode yourself? What have you tried and where are you stuck? This is too broad of a question, but we'd love to help you if you can narrow this down to a particular problem rather than a request for documentation and guidance.

Comment: I would like to point out ROBLOX is not a game, it is a site where people create games, and it runs on a modified version of Lua 5.1 called Rblx.Lua 5.1

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, there was no "hack". They removed the use of bytecode because of security vulnerabilities. And even more recently, removed loadstring entirely client-sided (and by default server-sided) due to exploits which took advantage of StringValues that scripting chat commands used in order to run their own code.

Comment: And finally - I'd remove it. It doesn't really have a good use anyway. In what case would you practically use loadstring (compiling code!)?

Comment: @warspyking: Being able to compile code within the language is one of the main benefits of using a scripting language. Think of databases that generate code by storing fragments of Lua scripts in database entries and so forth. So long as you don't have the ability to send bytecode through it, it isn't a security concern.

Comment: the "hack" is the fact you can insert opcodes in Lua functions to access sections where they don't have access to. This is a security concern in my game because things should be sandboxed and this could potentially be used to break out of the sandbox. Its not simply roblox that had this issue but Lua 5.1 and 5.2 in general. Since LuaJ bytecode appears to be different from Lua I cant effectively test if its an issue. I am not asking if people believe this is an issue or not the question is asking how to test this to see for myself if it is or not.

Comment: There is no sound way to test validity without actually running it. I think the best you can do is disable loading bytecode, also loading bytecode is not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: @Nicol I am aware of that, but for databases and such dofile is most certainly the effective way of handling it. The only reason I see loadstring being used for his running code that depends somehow on user input. (For example a very bad calculator program).

Comment: @warspyking: `dofile` requires a *filesystem*. I fail to see how it could handle Lua scripts *stored within* a database.

Comment: @Nicol Good point. What about require or load? I can't remember how they work entirely.

Comment: @Nicol There's always just boiling it down and parsing it.

Comment: The arguments here on "bug or feature" and "how impacting" are for the most part pointless in relation to my question. I merely need to find a way to write a pentest to see if accessing locals outside of function scope is possible in LuaJ so I know if I need to disable loadstring or not

Comment: It is possible, they can edit the bytecode using string.dump of the function to return (or just do something else) but then call `loadstring`. Case and point being if they can call `string.dump` on your function, they can see all the constants. It might be better to just disable `string.dump` or make sure it can't be used on those functions you want safe.

Comment: `string.dump` compiles the function and returns the chunk as a string. It's going to include all constant data (strings, numbers, etc.) that were defined in the function as well as others prototypes and so on. However upvalues are not going to be visible.

Comment: seeing constants isn't the issue. in SOME versions of Lua you can manipulate various opcodes and retrieve local variables left in the stack from other functions called letting you also have access to those locals which is bad if I don't want the player to have access to said local. That being said I DONT want to disable a function if I cant prove its an issue. Blocking stuff because it may or may not be an issue is just silly until you can prove it